# TPlink AC2800 to Linksys WRT3200

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

Normally fairly good with routing and networking but this has got me stumped.

I ran a LAN cable from a LAN port of my main ([TPlink AC2800](https://www.tp-link.com/uk/home-networking/dsl-modem-router/archer-vr2800/)) router to the WAN port of the [Linksys WRT3200](https://www.linksys.com/us/support-product?pid=01t340000046sOsAAI). I changed the IP on secondary (Linksys) to 192.168.2.1 (Third Octet) w/ DHCP enabled.

After rebooting both routers, I am now unable to login to the Linksys at 192.168.2.1, even though the cable runs directly to the router.

Previously I was running LAN to LAN and the Linksys was VPN enabled, so running normal internet on the first router (TPlink) and VPN on the Linksys, but I was unable to connect wirelessly to the Linksys.

After setting up here there and everywhere, I have become rather confused. Any idea why I am unable to access the Linksys router even with a cable?

Comment: Right! I have just figured it out. The issue was resolved by accessing the network adaptor from "open network & internet settings", then renewing the Ethernet network adaptor, reboot and resolve. Now able to access the router via the 192.168.2.1

Comment: TY for posting your solution; please make an answer to explain it. Comments are transient and won't be ported into the Q&A Infobase made from this site, whereas Answers Are Forever.